# Why am I getting constant time-out errors with Teams Shifts API? (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When querying a schedule in Teams Shifts which has sizeable amounts of shifts (say, 100+ shifts over a month - which is like a 30 person team working every day) we are constantly getting 504 errors (gateway timeouts)

We've tried using TOP and limiting the amount of days we're returning to reduce the request size, but the GRAPH API for Shifts is VERY limited in terms of search and filtering capacity

REQUEST EXAMPLE (FROM MS FLOW, via custom connector).

```
{
  "inputs": { 
    "host": { 
      "connection": { 
        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['shared_medicus365-5fconnector-5f455cfd1c6d1a89ed-5fce5269b428f1d481']['connectionId']" 
      }
    },
    "method": "get",
    "path": "/beta/teams/@{encodeURIComponent(items('fe_team')?['TeamID'])}/schedule/shifts",
    "queries": { 
      "$filter": "sharedShift/startDateTime ge @{outputs('composeStartOfDay')} and sharedShift/endDateTime le @{body('6monthsAhead')}",
      "$top": "1000"
    },
    "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
  },
  "metadata": { 
    "flowSystemMetadata": { 
      "swaggerOperationId": "ListTeamsShifts"
    }
  }
}
```

We're using the EXACT defined methods as described in the microsoft documentation.

We're getting a 504 response from GRAPH - gateway timeouts (again) any time the message size is anything beyond more than a few weeks worth of Shifts.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "437ad3be-be70-4bbe-b972-f9e24b588b5c",
      "date": "2019-09-03T19:01:57"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. We have looked at the logs.  With the fixes we've made, we have brought this down significantly. Less than 1% of our traffic spends more than 2s waiting to be routed between services. We are working on making this better. There is no fixed ETA for further improvements as of now.

Comment: Thanks! We had noticed the fix on our end as well. FYI - the OOTB Flow actions for Teams Shift "List Shifts" defaults to top 100 with no way to override it...

Is it possible to either increase to 2000 or give the option to set the TOP value?